# What is better way to compare class of two objects

Tags: java

I can compare two different objects to know whether they belong to same class or different using both `==` operator and `equals` method also. But which one is the better approach and how? Have a look on both approach that i followed. What is better way to compare class of two objects

```
 //r2 and r3 are two different objects    
//first approach   Using == operator
    boolean firstApproach = ((Object)(r2.getClass()) ==((Object)r3.getClass()));

//second approach   Using equals method to compare
            boolean secondApproach = ((Object)(r2.getClass())).equals(((Object)r3.getClass()));
            System.out.println("...firstApproach ..."+firstApproach +"...secondway.."+secondway );
```

Comment: aren't equals() and == overload the same?

Comment: @Paolo: not in Java. Operator overloading doesn't exist in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`java.lang.Class` inherits its `equals()` implementation from `java.lang.Object`:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  return (this == obj);
}
```

So it doesn't matter which way you compare classes. Also, class loaders are irrelevant as the behaviour will stay the same.

Answer (score 4):

Why not?

```
boolean sameClasses = r2.getClass() == r3.getClass();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply `r2.getClass() == r3.getClass()` without casts. If classes loaded by same classloader (I suppose in your case it's like that) then no problems with identity comparation.

Comment: Its still works with multiple class loaders, but perhaps not the way you might expect. ;)

Comment: Class loaders are irrelevant to this question, as `Class` inherits `Object.equals()`...

Comment: Yeah, of course 8) Just thought I had to to mention slightly this classloader stuff. '==' may return "unexpectable" result

Comment: @korifey - if you are suggesting that adding irrelevant stuff to an answer makes it more clear, I think you are mistaken ...

Comment: @Stephen C I don't think that this stuff is irrelevant. From question I supposed that @Sunil don't know that sometimes (if classes with same FQN and content were loaded by different classloaders) they are not equal as per `==` and `equals()`. So my answer contained some additional information that can be interesting to him (and it's related to the question).

Comment: @korifey - I see no indication whatsoever that the OP doesn't understand that.  Furthermore, since he doesn't mention classloaders, there's a good chance that his application is loaded by just one, and hence the issue simply does not arise.

Answer (score 1):

From a semantic perspective, there is no difference between using == or equals to compare two `Class` objects.  They give the same answer.

If there is any difference it is in the code's readability.  While Java experts should know that you can safely use == to compare classes, non-experts are less likely to know this and use of == is likely to ring alarm bells for them.  So arguably using `equals` makes your code more readable ... for the next guy, if not for you.  But this is a marginal call.

---

If you are concerned about readability, then you should get rid of the unnecessary `(Object)` type-casts.  They serve no purpose ... apart from making your code harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to know if its the same use **`.equals`** but more likely you might want to use **`instanceof`** to determinate if an object is in an instance of a class.

Comment: That cannot be decided from the OP's question. Maybe they really want to compare for equality...

Comment: @Angelo instanceof operator is useful when we have to check whether the object belong to any particular class. But in my case I want to check whether they belong to same class.

Comment: @LukasEder exactly, it cannot be decided thous every possibility should be shown so the OP can choose for himself what solves his problem best.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer: Stack Overflow is a Q&A. Not a Q&AAAAA[A1,A1',A2"] :-)

Comment: @LukasEder I thought about your last post for quite a while now and came to the conclusion that I disagree. SO is a Q&AAAAA because every question deserves any answer that fits to it because even if this Question is not meant that way, the answer could as well be correct and a future person looking for the answers to this question can be interested in all the answers as well. (Just my 2 cent)

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach has two main limitations:
1) if you have to implement this logic in multiple places in your code and also if you wish to change the criteria by which to check whether two objects are equal, you have to change your code in many different places
2) behind the scenes, Java often wants to compare two objects, but it doesn’t know by default how to determine equality, so you miss out on that if you don’t follow the second approach.

So, I feel the second approach is better.